# Clang & LLVM building for SPARC

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm writing a little self-educational project. It has to do with Clang and LLVM internals hacking.
But while I was investigating the code base and reading documentation, strange things were going on with the build process.

What I am trying to do for starters is to build LLVM and Clang for SPARC target. But this rather simple task turns out to be quiet challenging.

I use sources from the stable release 3.4.2 and folder tree looks like that:

```
llvm/
    ...
    projects/
        ...
        test-suite <-- test-suite-3.4.src.tar.gz extracted here
    tools/
        ...
        clang/ <-- cfe-3.4.2.src.tar.gz extracted here
            ....
            tools/
                ....
                extra <-- clang-tools-extra-3.4.src.tar.gz extracted here
```

And from the intermediate folder (which lays on the same level as llvm) I call the following:

```
../llvm/configure --disable-optimized --enable-targets=sparc \
 --prefix=/home/wf34/projects/helloClang/built
```

Surprisingly, resulting clang and llvm cannot deal with SPARC arch.

```
../built/bin/clang file2.c -S --target=sparc-unknown-linux -emit-llvm -o -
```

Gives (amongst the others) following line:

```
clang: warning: unknown platform, assuming -mfloat-abi=soft
```

Result is the same, if I write just --target=sparc.

Finally, attaching result of the **llc --version**:

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
LLVM version 3.3
Optimized build.
Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Host CPU: corei7-avx

Registered Targets:
cpp    - C++ backend
x86    - 32-bit X86: Pentium-Pro and above
x86-64 - 64-bit X86: EM64T and AMD64
```

Thank you for your insight and ideas!

**Edit**
Actually, having all that written, I have a guess that maybe I might have been mistaken while getting and untaring and setting the source from stable release. Maybe I would be better off following manual steps directly and getting source from svn trunk. I will fall back to that option if I won't receive any more meaningful suggestion.

Comment: Duplicate of [Unable to cross-compile to SPARC using clang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118854/unable-to-cross-compile-to-sparc-using-clang) - notably, 3.4.2 doesn't support Sparc.

Comment: Carl, Thanks. Lots of valuable info there)